# Working with math in javascript

Tags: javascript

I get the value `17.000`, 17 thousands.

```
var pay = document.getElementbyId("name").InnerHTML;
alert(pay);
```

it shows `"17.000"`. But if I do like this:

```
var f = (pay * 24);
alert(f);
```

it shows 408, not 408.000. It makes `17 * 24` not `17.000 * 24`. How to work around this?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually 17000 and not 17 with 3 decimal places? Because it is acting more like the latter, as if the culture using . to indicate 1000 place holder might not be set.

Comment: I just getting the value of a `<p>` tag. I'm trying to use `ParseFloat` but not working. Any idea?

Comment: "I'm trying to use ParseFloat but not working" I see no such code.

Answer (score 6):

The period is the decimal point in the English language. If you want `"17.000"` to be treated as *seventeen-thousand* and not *seventeen*, you have to remove the period:

```
var pay = +document.getElementById("name").innerHTML.replace(/\./g, '');
```

The unary plus (`+`) at the beginning converts the resulting string into a number. This is not strictly necessary in your example but can avoid problems in the long run.

Using `parseFloat` exposes the same problem as implicit type conversion.

If you want to format the number (i.e. convert it to a string with thousand separators) again, have a look at [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2901102/218196). Just use a period instead of a comma.

Comment: Does the `+` transform it into an number?

Comment: Understood, thanks @FelixKling! Isn't there a way to show the period? ;x